# Uploading to dropbox via node js fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have the following code to read from a stream and upload to Dropbox. But I'm getting a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
  at Function.Dropbox.Util.Xhr.Xhr.urlEncodeValue (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:3695:40)
  at Function.Dropbox.Util.Xhr.Xhr.urlEncode (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:3689:59)
  at Xhr.Dropbox.Util.Xhr.Xhr.paramsToUrl (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:3570:40)
  at Xhr.Dropbox.Util.Xhr.Xhr.prepare (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:3598:14)
  at Client.Dropbox.Client.Client._dispatchXhr (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:2137:11)
  at Client.Dropbox.Client.Client.resumableUploadStep (node_modules\dropbox\lib\dropbox.js:1454:19)
  .....
```

error when I try to run the code.If I give a 'false' as cursor, the error doesn't occur in step function, but still it occures in finish function. Can anyone help me on this?

```
stream.on('data', function (data) {
    client.resumableUploadStep(data, function (error, cursor) {
       if (error) {
          return  console.log(error);
       }    
    })
});

stream.on('end', function () {
     client.resumableUploadFinish(fileName, function (error, stats) {
         if (error) {
             return callback(error);
         }
         return callback(null, stats);
     });
});
```

**I used the following code and now it works.**

```
var pcursor = null;
var eventObject = new EventEmitter();
var counter = 0;
stream.on('data', function (data) {
    counter++;       
    client.resumableUploadStep(data, pcursor, function (error, cursor) {
            if (error) {                   
                return  callback(error);
            }
            counter--;
            pcursor = cursor;
            eventObject.emit('event');               
     });
});

stream.on('end', function () {
        eventObject.on('event', function () {
            if (counter == 0) {
                client.resumableUploadFinish(fileName, pcursor, function (error, stats) {
                    if (error) {
                        return callback(error);
                    }
                    return callback(null, stats);
                });
                counter = -1;
            }
        });

        eventObject.emit('event');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the cursor parameter to `resumableUploadFinish`. Also, you should be passing in a cursor to `resumableUploadStep` after the first call too.

I think the code you want is something like this (completely untested):

```
var cursor = null;
stream.on('data', function (data) {
    client.resumableUploadStep(data, cursor, function (error, new_cursor) {
        cursor = new_cursor;
    });
});
stream.on('end', function () {
    client.resumableUploadFinish(fileName, cursor, function (error, stats) {
        return callback(null, stats);
    });
});
```

Comment: There were 2 problems in my code. I tried once using cursor. But I used cursor=false rather than cursor=null. Other problem was finish method is called before the step functions are finished. therefore I added an event emitter. And now it works. :) thanks.